# Exception fixing "docBase" for context [/appName]

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, catalina

I migrated a project from Eclipse to IntelliJ, and when I want to run my configured Tomcat, I had this error:

> 16-May-2020 12:58:13.133 GRAVE [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart Exception fixing docBase for context [/appName]
>   java.io.IOException: Impossible to create directory [C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.34\webapps\appName]

I am not sure to have configure the context well.

Here is the META-INF/context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/appName"/>
<Context docBase="target/appName.war">
```

And here is the Tomcat config main page :

[image]

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Do you use any antivirus software? Also please try to run IDE with administrator rights.

Comment: No, I don't use any. I get back to Eclipse I think it's a better solution ^^

Comment: You can see the solutions for the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599507/error-deploying-java-war-file-severe-exception-fixing-docbase-for-context/14620816

Answer (score -1):

After four hours of beating my head against the wall:

Make sure your META-INF/context.xml says doc**B**ase and not doc**b**ase.

I need to have that case-insensitive feature removed from my eyes!

Comment: that's not the problem in this question. also, questions caused by simple typos should be closed instead of answered (see [answer])